# Ember-uploader s3 upload invalid preflight response?

Tags: amazon-s3, ember.js

I am using [Ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) to upload files directly from browser to s3. The cors policy that i have set is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4200</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Api response from nodejs server is as follows

```
{  
   "acl":"public-read",
   "awsaccesskeyid":"AKIAJJC5RMTQE7RNOUAA",
   "bucket":"georoot",
   "Cache-Control":"max-age=630720000, public",
   "Content-Type":"image/png",
   "expires":"2018-06-06T13:00:19.000Z",
   "key":"uploads/2018-05-30-212251_1366x768_scrot.png",
   "policy":"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxO9",
   "signature":"li7WlpwEYqX+jWqkjw72QE2DWug=",
   "success_action_status":"201"
}
```

The issue is the upload fails because of

> Failed to load http://georoot.s3.amazonaws.com/: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

On inspecting the network logs it shows me a `307` redirect and the upload fails. The configuration i have for the uploader plugin is as follows

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import EmberUploader from 'ember-uploader';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default EmberUploader.FileField.extend({

  filesDidChange(files) {
    const uploader = EmberUploader.S3Uploader.create({
      url: config.APP.UPLOAD_ENDPOINT
    });

    uploader.on('didUpload', response => {
      let uploadedUrl = $(response).find('Location')[0].textContent;
      uploadedUrl = decodeURIComponent(uploadedUrl);
    });

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      uploader.upload(files[0], { });
    }
  }
});
```

Can someone explain where i am going wrong ?